# I have problems with making it active on all 3 points in menu

Tags: php, html, css

I have problems with making it active on all 3 points, reasons they have the same file name 'categories.php'.

with activeI mean that it should make a hover each item on the menu you are in. And this code that I have here it makes hover on all three points, and I would like a solution to.

How can you solve the problem?

```
$active = ($page_frontend == 'categories.php' ? $active = ' class="active"' : '');
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=1">cats</a></li>';

$active = ($page_frontend == 'categories.php' ? $active = ' class="active"' : '');
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=2">doogs</a></li>';

$active = ($page_frontend == 'categories.php' ? $active = ' class="active"' : '');
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=3">mous</a></li>';
```

Comment: deleted my answer as I took the wrong idea. your question is a little bit misleading.

Comment: new answer added, with use `category_id` instead of page name

Comment: do not you think there is a solution? 
because if you see page = categories & category_id = 1 
                   page = categories & category_id = 2

Comment: my second answer only add `class="active"` clause for matching `category_id` from URL. is this still not the answer?? :-O be more descriptive then

Comment: just vote for the answer and we call it even!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `category_id` in your URL. That is what you should be using:

```
$category_id    =   $_GET["category_id"];

$active = ($category_id ==  1) ? ' class="active"' : '';
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=1">cats</a></li>';

$active = ($category_id ==  2) ? ' class="active"' : '';
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=2">doogs</a></li>';

$active = ($category_id ==  3) ? ' class="active"' : '';
echo '<li'.$active.'><a href="index.php?page=categories&category_id=3">mous</a></li>';
```